# Whats most efficient way to create 'running text' control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, user-interface, .net-4.0

I am about to make a WPF control which presents something similar to horizontal running text. However in reality yech vertical item of the display is a complex set of text and shapes (each item is different from another and driven by its underlying object properties). Once a vertical item added to the right it does not change also most left item must be removed from the view.

Now the question (and I dont know how to quickly benchmark these alternatives) is - what is more efficient way? Do I

- keep fixed number of vertical items (related to the control width) and scroll the underlying data items (everytime new item comes from the left) ?
- keep removing most left UI vertical item and moving it to the right changing its DataContext to a new data item?

or in short - **whats more efficient - rotation of UI items or data-bound underlying objects?**

Please note - the app is very-low latency and I want to squeeze the most out of the solution because I need to make sure that all chances to avoid bottleneck in the UI are taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as nobody could answer I had to benchmark it. in short - **UI scrolling is literally x10 times faster than data scrolling**.

If SO let attach files I'd put the project files in zip here for the curious.